# Price Alert:How to pass price product from a list of profucts to a popup?

Tags: php, symfony, popup, twig

I'm having a list of specific products,foreach product I have a button **Create Price Alert**.When I click on the button a pop up shows up and contains the price of the current product :

```
<link href="{{ asset('../web/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Products</h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Brand</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>URL</td>
        <td>Shop</td>
    </tr>
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td><img src="{{product.image}}" ></td>
            <td>{{product.brand}</td>
            <td>{{product.category}}</td>
            <td>{{product.url}}</td>
            <td>{{product.shop}}</td>
            <td><div class="box"><a class="button" href="#popup1">Create a price Alert</a></div>
   </td>
        <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popup">

                <h4>We will keep you updated</h4>
                <h4>Actual Price</h2> ???<br>       <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <h4>Desired amount</h4><input type="text" name="montant_souhaite" ><br>

            </div>
        </div>

    </tr>  

{% endfor %}    

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a lib to handle the popup, or are you using custom JS ?

If this is custom JS, there is many ways to do this, one of these being, adding a "data-price" attribute to your `<tr>` containing the price, and a "price" class to a `<span>` tag around the price in your popup.

Then, you can do this for example :

```
$('.box button').on('click', function(){
      $('#popup1 .price').html($(this).parents('tr').first().data('price'));
   }
);
```

Your html would look like this :

```
<link href="{{ asset('../web/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Products</h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Brand</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>URL</td>
        <td>Shop</td>
    </tr>
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr data-price='{{ product.price }}'>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td><img src="{{product.image}}" ></td>
            <td>{{product.brand}</td>
            <td>{{product.category}}</td>
            <td>{{product.url}}</td>
            <td>{{product.shop}}</td>
            <td><div class="box"><a class="button" href="#popup1">Create a price Alert</a></div>


            </td>
        <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popup">

                <h4>We will keep you updated</h4>
                <h4>Actual Price</h2> <span class='price'>???</span><br>       <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <h4>Desired amount</h4><input type="text" name="montant_souhaite" ><br>



            </div>
        </div>

    </tr>  


{% endfor %}    

</table>
```

If you are using a lib, see the doc, there is offen callbacks features available to add custom process to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to do it.

Try this :

```
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Image</td>
            <td>Brand</td>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>URL</td>
            <td>Shop</td>
        </tr>
        {% for product in products %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                <td><img src="{{product.image}}" ></td>
                <td>{{product.brand}</td>
                <td>{{product.category}}</td>
                <td>{{product.url}}</td>
                <td>{{product.shop}}</td>
                <td>
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="button" href="#popup-{{ product.id }}">Create a price Alert</a>
                </div>  
                </td>
                <div id="popup-{{product.id}}" class="overlay">
                    <div class="popup">
                        <h4>We will keep you updated</h4>
                        <h4>Actual Price</h2> {{ product.price }}<br>
                        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                        <h4>Desired amount</h4>
                        <input type="text" name="montant_souhaite" ><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tr>  
        {% endfor %}    
    </table>
```

You can use ajax too. You won't load all modals on the same page.

(btw, use th instead tr for your table head)

Answer (score 0):

This is the script :

```
<script>
    $('.alert').on('click', function(){
      $('.price').html($(this).data("price"));
   }
);
</script>
```

The html would look like this :

```
<link href="{{ asset('../web/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Products</h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Brand</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>URL</td>
        <td>Shop</td>
    </tr>
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td><img src="{{product.image}}" ></td>
            <td>{{product.brand}</td>
            <td>{{product.category}}</td>
            <td>{{product.url}}</td>
            <td>{{product.shop}}</td>
            <td><div class="box"><a class="alert button" data-price="{{ product.price }}" href="#popup1">Create a price Alert</a></div>


            </td>
        <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popup">

                <h4>We will keep you updated</h4>
                <h4>Actual Price</h2> <span class='price'></span><br>       <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <h4>Desired amount</h4><input type="text" name="montant_souhaite" ><br>



            </div>
        </div>

    </tr>  


{% endfor %}    

</table>
```